# Microsoft SQL single character full text search works with 25 out of 26 letters - but not "n" - returns all rows

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Found an interesting issue with quick search if you do single character search, 25 characters work fine, one doesn’t – “n”
A quick search select is of the form:

```
SELECT* FROM some_full_text_table WHERE CONTAINS(the_full_text_field, ' "n*" ')
```

This should search the full text field in the table for anything beginning with “n”.

Example data rows:

1. “name1 foo bar us cardiac”
2. “aname foo2 us echo”
3. “some name foo3 ct”
4. “the requested letter”

The query should return rows 1 and 3 as those are the only one that have words that begin with “n”.

The actual result is all rows are returned, even row 4, which has no n’s at all.

I truly believe this is an SQL bug. “na*” works as expected and returns 1 and 3.

Looking for a solution or work around

Here is an example SQL 2014

```
create table TestFullTextSearch (
    Id int not null,
    AllText nvarchar(400)
)

create unique index test_tfts on TestFullTextSearch(Id);
create fulltext catalog ftcat_tfts;
create fulltext index on TestFullTextSearch(AllText)
    key index test_tfts on ftcat_tfts
    with change_tracking auto, stoplist off
go

/* No n's in the data */

insert into TestFullTextSearch values (1, 'legacyreport Report Legacy 23049823490  20150713 Cardiac US ')
insert into TestFullTextSearch values (2, '123-45-678 foo bar  19450712 20020723 Exercise Stress US ')
insert into TestFullTextSearch values (3, '2048 jj goodguy xy2000 19490328 20150721 Cardiac US ')
insert into TestFullTextSearch values (4, '12345678 4.0 ALLCALCS  19650409 20031103 Cardiac Difficult US ')

select * from TestFullTextSearch where contains(AllText, '"n*"')

/* the result of the select */
1   legacyreport Report Legacy 23049823490  20150713 Cardiac US 
2   123-45-678 foo bar  19450712 20020723 Exercise Stress US 
3   2048 jj goodguy xy2000 19490328 20150721 Cardiac US 
4   12345678 4.0 ALLCALCS  19650409 20031103 Cardiac Difficult US
```

Comment: Using sql server 2012, windows server 2012 r2

Comment: Does fail for me on 2014 also. I would post actual data, but it contains personal information.

Comment: Ok - here is a contrived example that shows the problem

Comment: Yep, I can reproduce this using your example. By toying with the values, I can tell `n*` is matching the numeric values. Not sure if this is a bug or some undocumented feature... probably a bug though.